# how to use "No Record Found" in backgrid.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backgrid

hi i want to print in my grid "No Record Found" nothing found or 0 rows in table.
right now my grid showing result when it get data but when not it shows empty grid .so how can i print "no record found" when there is no record ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your BackGrid.Grid add the property emptyText which is a String.

For example:

```
var grid = new Backgrid.Grid({
  columns: columns,
  collection: myDataCollectoin,
  emptyText: "no data"
});
```